# Anyone know how to store many valus in barcode?

Tags: flutter

Hi guys Im trying to create a barcode, and inside the barcode will be the details of the customer. Is there any idea how can I put in more value?

Below is an example:

```
 Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 240.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        child: SfBarcodeGenerator(
                          value: data != null ? data.member_card_number : '',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

As you can see I only able to insert 1 value, which is customer card number only, is there anyway can add in more ?

Comment: Can you use a QR code instead?  Also, I hope that you don't use that to store any information that should be kept private.

Comment: @jamesdlin hi there, I'm currently working as an intern, and my boss told me to do it like that because this barcode is for customer to collect their points by scanning the barcode.

Comment: storing only the customer id in barcode is a good idea, if you need the customer name you should send the customer id to backend server and the server should return customer name

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of all required fields. Make a variable of that class and save all data. Convert it to a json string and convert it to a barcode. But make sure that the total characters are less than or equal to 44 if you are using code128 barcode